# Convert a Cloud service web role to Azure App service(Web app)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appfabric, azure-app-api

My subscription has been moved over to CSP subscription and i can no longer can use cloud services within it. For that matter, i guess i need to convert to Azure App services/Service fabric. The application is .NET MVC type and trying to convert to Service Fabric involves converting to .NET Core application which is more difficult i guess.

Is there a way i can convert to Azure App service (Web app) ? How would that go? How do we convert service config settings, service definitions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight forward answer is that convert the serviceconfig connection strings to the  in the web.config of the mvc web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert Web Roles to Service Fabric , you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service).

And if your app is .net MVC , yes, you need to upgrade it to .net core MVC. If you don't know how to upgrade, here is the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

If you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks George. I am taking a look at that.  I am currently looking at options converting from cloud service project to Azure App service which is there in ARM or CSP subscription. May i know the detailed steps for this too ?

Comment: Hello George, Can you help me with some tech documentation as to how to convert from cloud service to azure app service

Comment: @user3276487 sry, as far as i know , there is not a tool could help us migrate existing cloud service to Azure app service directly and automatically .